# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error (wechat)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, wechat

I added a wechat login to my xcode. However, these errors worked.
I do not know how to fix this error. please help me.

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
"__wechatstore",referenced from:
_Wechat__wechatstore_m13_992 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
_Wechat_wechatstore_m13_995 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
(maybe you meant: _Wechat__wechatstore_m13_992)
Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Activity Log Complete
```

Comment: Is the library compiled for x86 or ARM? The app seems to be designed for ARM64.

Comment: Do you mean that x86 or ARM dragon should not be in the library?

Comment: It seems you compiled the library for a different CPU architecture, probably x86. You need to compile it for ARM64.

Comment: If so, should I find and delete the x86 library?

Answer (score 0):

the message means that the symbol `__wechatstore` (which is likely a pointer to data structure) can't be found in any `arm64` binary supplied to the linker. So there are a couple things that could be going wrong:

- the Library with this symbol might not be getting included in compilation. (when build fails in Xcode, go to the 'report' tab in navigator, click on the failing build, and check out the failing "Link ..."  task
- the Library might be included but not be compiled for arm64. Now that I think of it, I think this is the most likely case. `arm64` support is a newer requirement from apple to support iPad Pro. I'd be willing to bet that the library probably only includes armv7. you can find out which architectures are included by running the `file` command on the library.

A possible temporary solution is to stop compiling for arm64, and try out just compiling armv7: to do that go to Project > Build Settings > Architectures > Architectures and change from $(ARCHS_STANDARD) `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` to `armv7`. (nb: idk but I wouldn't try to submit a binary without the proper architectures for the appstore)

Comment: thank you. However, this was a problem with function calls. Unity called a function that is not in xcode.